# sleep getting hang in shell script

Tags: command-line, suspend, cron

I had a cron script running on my Ubuntu PC ( 12.04.3 ) which periodically checks for disk space. There was a "sleep 5" also used in this script. This system was up for a month, but an issue is encountered. There were multiple instances of cron script running (around thousands) and multiple instances of "sleep".

When I killed one of the sleep process, cron script associated with it also completed.

Does sleep hangs often? Is it required to restart the machine to avoid this? Any other method to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a loop of things.

For example consider the following (bad) script, lets call it `check.sh`:

```
while :; du -sh /home/user >> /some/file 2>/dev/null; sleep 5; done
```

Now create a `cron` entry so that `check.sh` will run after every 30 minutes:

```
*\30 * * * * bash /path/to/check.sh
```

Lets consider the script first run at 10:00, the disk space will be checked and saved in a file. The tricky part is `sleep 5`, if you don't put a valid condition for closing it, it will pause the script for 5 secs and then will continue from the top meaning the same checking and writing operation. This loop will go on and on.

Again after 30 mins, `cron` starts a new process that will do the same thing over and over again. Remember the first process started by `cron` at 10:00 is still running.

This cycle will continue and in 6 hours you will have 13 of the same processes triggered by `cron` and most importantly every process is running in a indefinite loop.

In summary, while using `cron` you don't need things like `sleep 5` unless your operation demands something like that, in the latter case put a valid condition so that the process does not run indefinitely.